# Checking Conjugate symmetry in MRI k-space

Tags: matlab, symmetry

I have a `2-D k-space` data of size `256X256`. I learned that K-space data satisfies conjuage symmetry property `s(-x) = s*(x)`. How can I view this symmetry from k-space data using matlab. Though conjugate symmetry is not perfect due phase errors, I feel the magnitude part of complex numbers should be equal.

In matlab, I see matrix indexing is from 1 to 256. If I take 128 row as the central axis, there are 128 above central axis 127 below central axis. Then how I can associate matrix elements diagonally to check for conjugate symmetry?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using triu and tril 
(http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triu.html?refresh=true).